# Vue/Vuex: How to use Vuex to replace emitting functions that pass data?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I am looking into adding Vuex to my project to keep state organized.  How would I replace my emitted functions using Vuex though like in my example below? Can Vuex fully replace the need for emitting?

**Parent**

```
<child-component @handleUpdatePost="updatePost"></child-component>

methods: {
    updatePost(person) { 
        console.log(person)
        //do something
    }
}
```

**Child**

```
<button @click="clickButton"></button>

methods: {
   clickButton() {
        let person = "foo"
        this.$emit('handleUpdatePost', person)
   }
}
```

Comment: You can use events for a series of things that Vuex can take care of but they're just two different things. Vuex is good at keeping track of your app's data, changing it, and doing things when data is changing. For your example it ultimately depends on what the click is triggering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created an simple Vue 2 CLI application as an example of how you could replace an emit scenario with Vuex.

Store:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    message: 'Initial message'
  },
  mutations: {
    updateMessage(state, newMessage) {
      state.message = newMessage;
    }
  }
})

export default store;
```

Parent.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="parent">
    <h2>Parent.vue</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <label class="font-weight-bold">Message from Vuex: </label>
        <span>{{ message }}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
    <child />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Child from './Child.vue'

  export default {
    components: {
      Child
    },
    computed: {
      message() {
        return this.$store.state.message;
      }
    }

  }
</script>

<style scoped>
  label {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
  }
</style>
```

Child.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="child">
    <h3>Child.vue</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <form @submit.prevent="submitMessage">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>New Message:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" v-model="newMessage">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        newMessage: ''
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submitMessage() {
        this.$store.commit('updateMessage', this.newMessage);
        this.newMessage = '';
      }
    }
    
  }
</script>
```