# Catching emit's in Vue when using multiple slots

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Imagine these 4 Vue components:
`Parent`,
`Checkbox`,
`Parent_child` and
`Parent_child_child`

If `Parent` want to send `Checkbox` to `Parent_child` via slot. And `Parent_child` send the `Checkbox` further down to `Parent_child_child`. How should I handle when `Checkbox` emit's an input event?

1. Can I only catch it in `Parent` because that where's the `Checkbox` was made?
2. Or can I catch the input event in every 3 components?
3. Or is it up to me to catch it in the "lowest" component, here `Parent_child_child` to emit it up the chain, and to it for each level?

I don't think it's intuitive at all. Do I just have to learn the rule and remember it, or is there a more intuitive and natural way of seeing this scenario?

Comment: (1) yes (2) yes (3) possible but unnecessary. You might be overthinking this :)

Comment: Thanks alot. Yeah I hear that alot. It's not all bad :)

Comment: I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66440821/vue-vuex-how-to-use-vuex-to-replace-emitting-functions-that-pass-data) earlier about replacing emits with Vuex.  See the first (and currently only) answer.